# neo4j performance multiple queries same data

Tags: performance, graph, neo4j, cypher

I'm solving a complex pathfinding problem in my database that can't be expressed in Cypher, so I need to divide it up into multiple queries (and write a complex recursive set of functions).
My question is regarding performance of doing multiple queries on the same node. When query A returns a node X and node X is needed in the next query B, what is the best way of telling neo4j to look for node X in query B?

The most simple way would be to give every node a name, and then return X.name in query A and use WHERE X.name = ... in query B. I suppose this is really slow because neo4j would have to check every name of every node in the database. Is there a faster way or is this actually the best?

EDIT: because the question might not be completely clear, I'll give some more information on the problem I'm solving

I want to get the person that has the best knowledge of a given skill, for example physics. In the database there's a connection between physics and another skill, for example maths, that tells knowledge of maths is usefull for physics. But now I need to know how skilled every person is in maths which is the same process again. This would make sense to do recursively, but as far as I know there's no recursion in Cypher, so I'll have to split it up in multiple queries.

What I want to prevent is that when a link is found between physics and maths, the function that will calculate every person's knowledge in maths does not have to go through every node in the database to find the one where name = 'maths', which is very inefficiënt.

Comment: Can you give us your `best skill` query , and why not create a graph console for that (http://console.neo4j.org/) ? I think it's possible to do it in one query.
To respond to your firstquery, the best way to retrieve a node it's by its id, but you do all your queries inside the same transaction (neo4j's id are reused)

Comment: this parcticular problem can indeed be solved with just cypher, but there are a lot more relations than I described here.

Comment: I just started the project so I can't exactly tell you how the data is going to look like and what the relation types are, but here is an [example](http://console.neo4j.org/r/6f86h6)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I understood your question completely, but I think that a good starting point is to create an [index](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/schema/index/#query-schema-index) in the `name` property of your nodes. From the docs:

> A database index is a redundant copy of information in the database
>   for the purpose of **making retrieving said data more efficient**. This
>   comes at the cost of additional storage space and slower writes, so
>   deciding what to index and what not to index is an important and often
>   non-trivial task.

```
CREATE INDEX ON :NodeLabel(name)
```

Comment: I'll try this! Not sure though if it's faster because I only need the indexed node very shortly and the indexation probably also takes time.

Comment: @JesseMaas yes. From the docs: _Note that the index is not immediately available, but will be created in the background._

Comment: I added some more information on the problem, is it more clear now?

Comment: @JesseMaas your issue is a bit more clear now. But I think you should follow logisima's suggestion and create a console with sample data. This way we can help you more easily.